# intelligent tracking prevention in safari - is there alternative for cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, web, safari, local-storage

according to the new  intelligent tracking prevention (ITP) in safari that delete cookies after 30 days.
i need my cookie to stay longer than 30 days and looking for alternative for cookies.
does anyone here knows if using Local-Storage instead of cookies can help? they delete it after 30 days as well?
if they do, is there any alternative?